# Get original number when reversing a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to to make a simple price update by percentage, the increase works fine but the subtract is always below the original number, ie:

```
Increase: 1 + 5% = 1,05   //  Subtract: 1,05 - 5% = 0.998
```

How can I update my code to get the same number after subtract?

This is the code I'm using:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private cmd As SqlCommand
    Private cnn As New SqlConnection
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim iofile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "/connect.txt")
        Dim ioline As String
        ioline = iofile.ReadToEnd
        cnn = New SqlConnection(ioline)
        cnn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("update saprod_01 set price1=price1+(price1*@calc1/100); 
        update saprod_01 set price2=price2+(price2*@calc2/100); 
        update saprod_01 set price3=price3+(price3*@calc3/100);", cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@calc1", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@calc2", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@calc3", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TextBox3.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where @calc1 (and 2 & 2) will have a positive integer value for an increase, and a negative integer value for a decrease.

Comment: If by substract you mean reverse it's just simple math, divide by 105 multiply by 100

Comment: i know the mathematical answer but i cant get it to work in my code, can you give me an example with the code i'm using?, the idea is to type for example: "5 or -5" on the textboxes and get the math done through the code

Comment: the calc values are user input

Comment: They're used to update three price columns on the database, i just copied the full code, sorry about that

Comment: that's the idea, a full update on every record

Comment: they're 3 different prices, price1, price2, price3, used for three different purposes, if the price3 is below the average market price the user will use the TextBox3 and type "15", that will update all the records on price3 column using the sql statement: update saprod_01 set price3=price3+(price3*@calc3/100

Comment: i used a default value for all the text boxes (0) in case the user is going to update only two columns (price1 and price3) and left the other one (price2) empty with a "zero" that left no changes on the records

Comment: to add the percentage just type the natural number, to remove a percentage the "-" will be used for example "-5"

Comment: if you wanna get in chat just lemme know, i can give you more details but its pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

To get the original number after applying a percentage increase and then a decrease, you need to divide by (1 + percentage) instead of subtracting the percentage.

For example, after increasing a value by 5%, you'll get `value * 1.05`. To revert it, you'll divide by `1.05` rather than subtracting 5%.

The code should be adjusted as:

```vb
cmd = New SqlCommand("
update saprod_01 set price1=price1*(1 + @calc1/100); 
update saprod_01 set price2=price2*(1 + @calc2/100); 
update saprod_01 set price3=price3*(1 + @calc3/100);", cnn)
```

And to subtract or revert:

```vb
cmd = New SqlCommand("
update saprod_01 set price1=price1/(1 + @calc1/100); 
update saprod_01 set price2=price2/(1 + @calc2/100); 
update saprod_01 set price3=price3/(1 + @calc3/100);", cnn)
```

This approach will ensure that you get back to the original number after the subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

The following should do what you need based on your clarifications. You can just use a case expression to determine whether you use the formula to add or reverse the amount.

- note you only need a single update statement for multiple columns.

```
update saprod_01 set
  price1 = case when @calc1 > 0
    then price1 * (100 + @calc1) / 100
    else price1 / (100 + @calc1) * 100
    end
  , price2 = case when @calc2 > 0
    then price2 * (100 + @calc2) / 100
    else price2 / (100 + @calc2) * 100
    end
  , price3 = case when @calc3 > 0
    then price3 * (100 + @calc3) / 100
    else price3 / (100 + @calc3) * 100
    end;
```